# Very high CPU usage when playing web video

Tags: firefox, video, chromium, youtube

I have just set up a new laptop - Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I've noticed very high CPU usage when watching web video. From a fresh boot, I start a single Firefox (or Chromium) window, navigate to e.g.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SfXqTENV_Q

and the video starts playing, and I watch (via htop) the CPU usage for firefox jump to about 90% and stay there.

I've reproduced this on both Firefox and Chromium, and on youtube, BBC iplayer and vimeo.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I've just installed the latest nvidia drivers, the package was called nvidia-387. But, no mention of nvidia in lscpi makes me think that maybe they are not actually being used:

```
martin@martin-XPS-13-9360:~$ lspci | grep nvidia
martin@martin-XPS-13-9360:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
```

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers if you haven't already. If you have, the version should have been mentioned in your question.